# How to get HH:MM from time() difference?

Tags: php

In database i store time which i get from time function in php. Also store time() different between end time and start  time.  Now i want to get HH:MM from this difference.

To show HH:MM i use

```
gmdate('H:i',$m['timedifference']);
```

Is this ok ? or am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

You need to convert `time` to `strtotime`.

```
gmdate('H:i',strtotime($m['timedifference']));
```

Comment: only if time is not seconds,

Comment: actually i am creating time puch so should i store time in Y-m-d H:i:s ? because i also store difference in database so that i may not need to recalculate in report. Have you any suggestion for me regarding how to store two time difference in database ?

Comment: Actually i am already store time in database and so i use gmdate('H:i',$m['timedifference']);

Comment: It seems that i need to store Y-m-d H:i:s in database because time() takes more character to store. right ?

Comment: what datatype of your database table column?

Comment: have you try again?

Comment: Actually problem is that suppose any one forget to enter time out then in case if i will store second different then its value will be too large. So i have changed to Y-m-d H:i:s in db.  I also want to store time difference in db. so that i can calculate total time easily. any suggestion ?